# Ethereum Null Address List

Tags: etherscan, addresses, genesis

I found `Null Address` list in etherscan.

https://etherscan.io/accounts/label/burn

I know that null address is `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` because of it is genesis address, but I found other address using Null Address.

Is there any rules for using null address?
Or can I use anything?

Answer (score 2):

In general, yeah you can choose any arbitrary address that you want for null address.

The reason you can do that is because it is almost impossible for you to choose a random address that somebody already has a private key for it. Let's do some math to prove it, an address is 256 which mean it can go up to 2^256. The earth population at this time (12/2021) is about 7.9 billion but i will make it 8 billion for ease in calculation. Assume every person in the planet has 100 private key corresponding to the address they have. Then the possiblity that you can choose an address that they already choosen is about 10^-66 (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=800%2C000%2C000%2C000+%2F+2%5E256).

The possiblity that you win a Powerball is one in 292.2 million, roughly 10^-9 (https://www.thebalance.com/what-are-the-odds-of-winning-the-lottery-3306232). So you will have to win Powerball roughly 7 times in a row to even get a chance in picking a random address that somebody already has the private key given that everybody on the earth have 100 private keys